# How to prune orphaned jobs using Jenkins Declarative Pipeline syntax?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

How to prune orphaned jobs using Jenkins Declarative Pipeline syntax?
There is `logRotator` but it's not enough. All jobs for deleted branches are still there.